# Does Chrome changes Access-Control-Allow-Origin?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, cross-domain

Browsing with Chrome to my nodejs web site. The Access-Control-Allow-Origin value that I see in Chrome developers tools is different from the one that I define in my nodejs

In my nodejs

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "siteA");
```

When I look at the Chrome developers tools under Network -> Response Headers I see

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: siteB
```

Tried with Edge - working fine

I clean the site data using Application->clean storage - didn't help

The error code I get in chrome is

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'XXXXX' from origin 'siteA' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'siteB' that is not equal to the supplied origin.
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please change `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "siteA");` to `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");`

```
 app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","POST","GET")
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type,authorization,Accept");

  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true'); 
  next();
});
```

Please copy and paste this code in your servers index.js file.I think this should work.

Comment: tried res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*"); did not help, I do have the other 3 lines you mentioned

Comment: I edited the code. Can you please try that and let me know if that is working or not.

Comment: I have this code with no change, also add the  res.setHeader( 'Vary', 'Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method'); - did not help

Comment: well I solved the cors error with this.@user1726407 there is one another way to solve cors error by using plugin .https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors check this plugin